# Solve $x'(t)=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please correct me I have a differential equation to solve: 
 

 $ x'(t)=x$ 
 

As I will interpret it, it would be $ \frac{dt}{dx}=x$ it's a separable and exact equation.

 I will multiply by $dx$, integrate both sides and end up with 
 
$ x^2 = 2t+c$

 
I checked the answer on WolframA. and I'm wrong the answer is $ x(t)=ce^t$. Could you please explain me why I'm wrong and give hints how to solve it properly. 

 
Thank you

Comment: $x'(t)$ stands for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ rather than $\frac{dt}{dx}$

Comment: Obviously yes. That simple. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I liked the way you presented the post: you explained very well what caused your confusion, so it was easy to find the mistake.